# how to get Request.ApplciationPath in Aspnet5

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

Consider URL: http://website.com/application
In earlier version of .Net,

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host = "website.com"
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath = "/application"
```

In Aspnet5 RC1, getting host is fine, but how to get `Request.ApplicationPath`?

Comment: Have you looked at HttpContext.Request.PathBase?  Also https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Using `IApplicationEnvironment`:

```
private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnvironment;
public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment)
{
    _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var path = _appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
    // other codes
}
```